# If/Else statement in view using razor not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I created this code and passed it to a partial view:

```
MealCurrentDetails mcd = new MealCurrentDetails
{
   id = 1,
   name = "Name",
   description = "desc",
   price = 99,
   availability = 0
};

return PartialView("MealDetails", mcd);
```

This is the partial view I've created.

```
@model WebProg.Models.MealCurrentDetails

@if (Model != null)
{
    <dt>Meal Name</dt>
    <dd>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
    </dd>
    <dt>Description</dt>
    <dd>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)
    </dd>
    <dt>Price</dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.price)
    </dd>
    <dt>Availability</dt>
    if(model.availability == 0)
    {
       <dd class="text-success">Available</dd>
    }
    else
    {
       <dd class="text-warning">Not available</dd>
    }
}
```

The if statement in my View is not working and I can't understand why. Any ideas how will I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `Model.availability` not `model.availability`.

```
@model WebProg.Models.MealCurrentDetails

@if (Model != null)
{
    <dt>Meal Name</dt>
    <dd>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.name)
    </dd>
    <dt>Description</dt>
    <dd>
       @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.description)
    </dd>
    <dt>Price</dt>
    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.price)
    </dd>
    <dt>Availability</dt>
    if(Model.availability == 0)
    {
       <dd class="text-success">Available</dd>
    }
    else
    {
       <dd class="text-warning">Not available</dd>
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also need the `@`.

Comment: @KirkLarkin : no . I don't need it. as it is already inside `if` block. I will need `@` only when if write `if` in between any html element.

Comment: Funny. I tried this and it wasn't working a while ago. Now it works. Thank you.

Comment: @SCarmichael : it shouldn't happen. :P . anyway accept it as answer. :)